# Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services web services convert html to pdf

Tags: sql, web-services, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, pdf-generation

I knew that you can develop customised code to generate pdf report via SQL Server Reporting Services (web services API).

My question is: can you utilize the same mechanism to convert any HTML code into pdf file?

My team lead wants me to convert html to pdf in this way to try to utilize the existing report services reference.

Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware that can't be done, although of course you could regenerate the report as a PDF if you know the parameters used, and the data hasn't changed since the original was created.

Alternatively why don't you use a HTML to PDF convertor? There are quite a variety available.

Lastly you could ask your team lead to demonstrate how to do it, that's one of his jobs after all, to lead the way.